# How do I save as certain file type in sublime text 2?

Tags: lua, sublimetext2

I am very new to programming and started using sublime text 2 as an editor for corona sdk and I am really liking it aside from one small problem.

My Problem:

When I open a new file in sublime text and then save it as a .lua file it does not save as a .lua. I use the drop down menu to select save as .lua. When I look at the file in my project folder the filetype is specified as only "file".  This problem wont stop me from using sublime but it is very annoying. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just typing the full filename you want when you save it, e.g. `filename.lua`

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response. I feel like an idiot for not trying that. Seems to have fixed my issue. :)

Comment: Yeah, I think programs vary in that respect. Some will add the extension if not found, some just filter the view before saving as whatever you type!