# Saving a cljs file

Tags: javascript, file, sublimetext2, clojurescript

In the command prompt the following directories have been created:

```
                $ mkdir -p src-cljs/webviz
                $ mkdir -p resources/js
```

I am trying to create the file:

```
                src-cljs/webviz/core.cljs
```

containing

```
               (ns webviz.core)
               (defn ^:export hello [world]
               (js/alert (str "Hello, " world)))
```

in `Sublime Text 2`.

If I try to save the file I don't have an option for `.cljs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this? [How do I save as certain file type in sublime text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244192/how-do-i-save-as-certain-file-type-in-sublime-text-2)

> Try just typing the full filename you want when you save it, e.g.
>   filename.lua

Comment: I had already done that. My uncertainty in the correctness is that the save as file type does not contain `.cljs`. So, the file saves but sublime doesn't seem to recognize the file type. If I save a `.clj` or something contained with the save as file type the text changes color and the box in front of the file is no longer plain white. Sorry for being verbose but I am trying my best to describe this situation without the proper language it seems. @Joaquin